# How would I go about intercepting EditText like Dropbox Passwords

Tags: android

I'm looking to achieve some specific functionality that I've observed using the Dropbox Passwords app.

The app can seemingly intercept the user editting a text (I'm assuming it's an EditText). I'm wondering how I can do this myself!

Example with Snapchat:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to [autofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill).

Comment: Oh you're probably right of course, I just didnt think it had those capabilities! Thanks